# PHP $_POST Alert

Tags: php, alert

I have this form which allows the input of any product quantity from 1-10:

```
<form method='post' action='cart.php'>
<input type='number' name='quantitychange' size='2' min='1' max='10' value=".$_SESSION["itemsSelected"][$i][1].">
<input type='hidden' name='ProductID' value=".$_SESSION["itemsSelected"][$i][0].">
<input type='submit' value='Update'>
</form>
```

And another form (button) to display a selection of payment modes:

```
<form action='cart.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='next'>
<input type='submit' value='Select Payment Mode'>
</form>
```

What I want to happen is that when a user did not input anything (1st form), ex. null or 0, I want to display an alert box that says 'Product quantity can't be null or 0'.

Here's my code for that:

```
if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
if ($_POST['quantitychange']==null || $_POST['quantitychange']==0) {
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Product quantity can't be null or 0.');
</script>
<?php
}
else {
echo "
//Payment modes here
";
}
}
```

The error is that even when a user inputs a quantity bet. 1 to 10, it still displays the alert message. Any help? Thank you.

By the way, the input type "**number**" only works in Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a small javascript (or jQuery) function to validate the form before posting it. Have this function throw up the alert if your condition isn't met and then return false. If the condition is met, return true, and it gets submitted.

*Edited to add* since this might get googled, I'll help a bit with code snippet I have used. The below example is jQuery and was used in production for a web application I made for my employees. `document.form.doit.submit();` should be the pure javascript way of submitting the form.

```php
<script type="text/javascript">
function subForm() {
    // document.form.doit.submit();
    if( test condition passes ) {
        $('#save_order').submit();
    }
}
</script>

<form id="save_order" action="oms_db.php" method="POST">
<input id="doit" type="button"
    value="i am a button" onClick="subForm();">
</form>
```

Comment: +1. Since you're already using javascript, you can just check whether the quantity field is empty onBlur, and then the user doesn't have to submit the entire form and wait for the receiving page to load before being notified of the error.

Comment: I like putting validation on the submit button (or making the submit button simply a function call to something like submitMyNumberForm) and the function can then do whatever user interaction you like. 

If you onBlur() then if they drag their mouse across it unintentionally, they get yelled at. Not cool! Also, the form doesn't reload, when the function finds the data invalid and returns false, it's as though the button wasn't pushed at all and the page visitor is still watching it. I'll use jQuery or javascript to put focus on that input field and/or make it red.

Comment: Are you saying that moving the pointer over an input field (while dragging?) causes it to acquire focus? I've never had that happen before. I thought onBlur only happened if they'd previously clicked on or otherwise navigated to a field.

Comment: onBlur() isn't the same as onChange. I have seen it behave like onMouseOut(). Probably depends on the browser. Heck, I decided against onBlur() so long ago that its behavior might be better now. :P :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some error in your forms. Instead of the below:

```
<input type='number' name='quantitychange' size='2' min='1' max='10' value=".$_SESSION["itemsSelected"][$i][1].">
<input type='hidden' name='ProductID' value=".$_SESSION["itemsSelected"][$i][0].">
```

you should be using something like this:

```
<input type='number' name='quantitychange' size='2' min='1' max='10' value="<?php echo $_SESSION["itemsSelected"][$i][1]; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='ProductID' value="<?php echo $_SESSION["itemsSelected"][$i][0]; ?>">
```

The value parameters in the hidden input fields needs to be echoed from PHP. What you have now is like the value is simple strings ".$_SESSION["itemsSelected"][$i][0].".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use

```
 if(empty($_POST['quantitychange'])) { echo 'yourerror'; }
```

As it is far cleaner then your script. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Update:
Also, you can't use two seperate forms like you do, your browser only posts whats between

```
<form>
</form>
```

Using only one will fix your problem.